# Stochastic order of the minimum of a stopped sequence of random times

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $S_k$ and $S'_k$ be two sequences of independent random times such that for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$ it holds that $S'_k \leq_{st} S_k$, that is $S'_k$ is stochastically smaller than $S_k$ which means that $P(S'_k > t) \leq P(S_k > t)$ for all $t \geq 0$.

For each non-decreasing $u : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ it follows that $u(S'_1, \dots, S'_n) \leq_{st} u(S_1, \dots, S_n)$. In particular $\min(S'_1, \dots, S'_n) \leq_{st} \min(S_1, \dots, S_n)$ and $T'_n := \sum_{k=1}^n S'_k \leq_{st} \sum_{k=1}^n S_k =: T_n$ for each $n$.

Now let $T > 0$ and consider the random variables $X := \min \{ S_n \ | \ T_n < T \}$ and $X' := \min \{ S'_n \ | \ T'_n < T \}$.

Question: Is $X' \leq_{st} X$?

I would expect that $X' \leq_{st} X$ since $S_n'$ is "smaller" than $S_n$ and in addition there could be "more" $S_n'$ that sum up to the largest number $T_n' < T$ than $S_n$ that sum up to $T_n < T$ such that their minimum can be even smaller since there is a possibly larger set on which the minimum is considered.

I tried to prove by partitioning
$$ P(X' > t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty P(X' > t, T'_n < T \leq T'_{n+1}) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty P(S'_1 > t, \dots, S'_n > t, \sum_{k=1}^n S'_k < T, \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} S'_k \geq T) $$
which I cannot estimate by the corresponding partitioning for $X$ since there is a $\sum_{k=1}^n S'_k < T$ inequality involved in the equation.

Also when performing several tests with some computer algebra system, I let $S_k$ and $S'_k$ be some Poisson processes and I got that some terms in the above partitioning are smaller and other terms are larger then the corresponding terms in the partitioning of $X$ when computing the exact symbolical results first and evaluating them only in the end to a numerical quantity (such that I hope that this is not a numerical error). Thus, there must be another way to prove the above conjecture.

Comment: One can realize every $S_k$ and $S'_k$ on a common probability space, in such a way that $S'_k\leqslant S_k$ almost surely, for every $k$. Then $T'_n\leqslant T_n$ almost surely hence the random sets $A=\{n\mid T_n\leqslant T\}$ and  $A'=\{n\mid T'_n\leqslant T\}$ are such that $A\subseteq A'$ almost surely. Furthermore $X=\inf\{S_n\mid n\in A\}$ and $X'=\inf\{S'_n\mid n\in A'\}$, hence $X'\leqslant Y\leqslant X$ almost surely, where $Y=\inf\{S'_n\mid n\in A\}$, QED.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that there might be a more direct approach without moving to the almost sure representation. The problem is that such an almost sure representation for the comparison of random variables (Strassen Theorem) is in general not constructive (possibly involves the axiom of choice?).

Comment: Or, since there is independence, one can realize everything using i.i.d. random variables uniform on (0,1) and inverse functions of CDFs.

Comment: I see. Is it right to say that the non-constructiveness of Strassen's Theorem is due to possible dependence of the random elements to be compared that take values in an arbitrary (partially ordered) Polish space? It seems to be like the similar issue with Kolmogorov's extension theorem (relying on the axiom of choice and concerning dependent random elements in terms of the family of finite-dimensional distributions) in contrast to the simple product of probability measures for independent random elements.

Comment: Exactly. Strassen is valid in a hugely more extensive setting.

Comment: It is possibly worth to mention that we now have introduced dependence for the couplings $\tilde{S}_k$ and $\tilde{S}'_k$ of $S_k$ and $S'_k$ for each fixed $k$ where $\tilde{S}_k := \phi(U(x))$ and $\tilde{S}'_k(x) := \phi'(U(x))$ where $U$ is (the same!) uniformly distributed random variable on $(0,1)$ and $\phi, \phi'$ are the quantile functions of $S_k$ and $S'_k$. From $\phi'(y) \leq \phi(y)$ for all $y \in [0,1)$ we have $\tilde{S}'_k(x) \leq \tilde{S}_k(x)$ for all $x \in (0,1)$. (When taking two independent $U$'s we do not get the desired almost sure comparison.)